# json.net JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync ISO 8601 Date

Tags: azure, json.net

Edit 2:

I created a Windows phone 8 application and included Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices; with the same class as the offending code below in the original question I created a record that json.net DID successfully deserialize.

```
 [{"id":1,"DataLoggerName":"Ben Walkin","Time":"2013-02-19T18:39:51.733Z",
[{"id":1,"DataLoggerName":"JHANetDuino","Time":"2013-02-19T16:46:55.205K",
```

Re reading the [ISO 8601 Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) I now interpret the 'K' as the culprit. Only 'Z' Zulu time is acceptable. Offsets are expressed numerically. "*Time zones in ISO 8601 are represented as local time (with the location unspecified), as UTC, or as an offset from UTC.*"

I will attempt to post a solution for the client posting the 'K' .netmf with an unsupported .dll to allow creation of table data in Azure.

Edit 1:

I included json.net in my Solution to step through error and found this:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146233088   Message=Could not convert string to DateTime:
>   2013-02-18T06:35:25.604K. Path '[0].Time', line 1, position 74.

Original Question

I have a windows store app that works with Json data that I constructed with .php. I've recently been enhancing it to work with windows Azure. I 'own' the code and can correct it to be useful to others and follow 'standards' to that end I'm trying to standardize my Json and specifically the DateTime (is confusing me)

Is this a valid ISO 8601 Date? "Time":"2013-02-18T06:35:25.604K"
and is this NOT a valid ISO 8601 date? "Time":"2013-02-11 16:25:54"

The valid date has the 'T' between the data and time, the invalid has a ' ' ?

Data in from old working .php code

```
    [{"Time":"2013-02-11 16:25:54","Temperature0":"74.38478","Temperature1":"57.142857142857146"},{"Time":"2013-02-11 16:26:54","Temperature0":"74.38478","Temperature1":"57.753357753357754"},
```

Data in from new Azure crashing code

```
    [{"id":1,"DataLoggerName":"JHA NetDuino","Time":"2013-02-18T06:35:25.604K","Temperature0":82.78388278388276,"Temperature1":0},
```

This is the old working code reading what appears to me to be invalid json ISO 8601 date data as there is no 'T' between date and time.

```
                var strJson = await GetJsonHistoricalTemperatureData.GetHistoricalTemperatureData();
        return await JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<ObservableCollection<HistoricalTemperatureData>>(strJson);


        public class HistoricalTemperatureData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DataLoggerName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public double Temperature0 { get; set; }
    public double Temperature1 { get; set; }
}
```

If I read the Azure data with the same code I get an exception error on json.net

```
    A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

From all that I've read it seems that the app should NOT have been working with the original date data and should with the new Azure data. It seems that the Azure data is more correct following the ISO 8601 format. I would like to align my old .php code to produce this (easily done) and *fix* the windows store app to properly deserialize the Json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re reading the [ISO 8601 Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) article I now interpret the 'K' as the culprit. Only 'Z' Zulu time is acceptable. Offsets are expressed numerically. *"Time zones in ISO 8601 are represented as local time (with the location unspecified), as UTC, or as an offset from UTC."*